# Why to use "printf" instead of "println" while printing hello in if statement

Tags: java

I want to print "hello" without using semicolon.While using for loop for printing hello i came to know println and printf both can be used for printing hello. But in case of if only printf is used for printing hello.When i used println in if statement its showing "void type not allowed here".What does this error means and why println cannot be used in if statement??

```
public class withoutsemicolon
{ 
public static void main(String [] args)
{   
for(int i=0;i<=4;System.out.println("hello"+i+"\n"),i++)
{}
if(System.out.println("hello"+"\n")!=null)
{}
}
}
```

Comment: So sir plss tell me how to print hello without using semicolon

Comment: Why? Just why? Please tell me why do you want to do this?

Comment: The question was asked in interview

Comment: Please take the time to format your code. It's *really* hard to read at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is `printf` returns `PrintWriter` which you can compare to `null`. `println` returns `void` i.e. nothing which you can't compare to null. A couple of additional options to print without using semicolon in your program are `while` and `try`. All the mentioned options:

```
if(System.out.printf("hello\n") == null){}
while(System.out.printf("hello\n") == null){}
try(Closeable c = System.out.printf("hello\n")){}
```

One additional option and my favorite is to tell the interviewer that you refuse to answer stupid questions but that's a luxury not everybody have.

Comment: thanks sir now i can surely ans this question in interviews